# Problems with sorting algorithm (descending order) in C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I have a function that I want to be able to sort an array in descending order. The function takes an array as argument and the array always has a length of 10. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void printHighScore(int *highScore){
    int i, j;
    int temp;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        for (j = i + 1; j < 10; j++){
            if(highScore[i] < highScore[j]){

                temp = highScore[i];
                highScore[i] = highScore[j];
                highScore[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("1: %d\n2: %d\n3: %d\n4: %d\n5: %d\n", highScore[0], highScore[1], highScore[2], highScore[3], highScore[4]);

}


int main(){
    int *highScore[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    printHighScore(highScore);
    return 0;
}
```

I expect the output to be the following:

> 1: 10 
> 2: 9 
> 3: 8 
> 4: 7 
> 5: 6

Since those are the highest values of the array. However, I get the following output:

> 1: 5 
> 2: 4 
> 3: 3 
> 4: 2 
> 5: 1

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `main`, you have:

```
int main(){
    int *highScore[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    printHighScore(highScore);
    return 0;
}
```

The declaration for `highScore` is wrong.  You've declared an array of pointers, not an array of integers.  You should have gotten a warning when you compiled the code, since it passes an incorrect pointer type to `printHighScore`.  Change the declaration to:

```
    int highScore[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
```

That should fix the problem.

The reason you saw what you did is due to pointers being larger than integers on your platform.  As a result, when interpreted as an integer array, you had `1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, ...` (assuming a little-endian architecture).  So you were only sorting half of the array, with the result being 5 ... 1 followed by five zeros.

In general, you should always pay attention to warnings, especially warnings about incompatible pointer types.  They are almost always bugs and are usually easy to fix.

Comment: Oh I see now. Thank you very much for the very quick answer!